# How do I Morph one SVG to another?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've looked around for about an hour only to resort to SO; I found https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/ . This tutorial says "create two svg's with same amount of points" and then randomly jumps to:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">

  <polygon fill="#FFD41D" points=" ... shape 1 points ... ">

  </polygon>

</svg>
```

There are no references to either of the SVG images after creation. The tutorial doesn't explain whats going on... or what to do with the images I created - I'm assuming these "points" are some sort of co-ordinate system that plot out the image, and the value for the viewbox attribute seem random - .

I looked at other solutions such as GreenSocks svgmorphing tool but for the task of morphing two 40px images together it seemed over-complicated having to go through learning all the syntax ect.

( The two images are located at:

http://tobi.freetzi.com/arr.svg and

http://tobi.freetzi.com/add.svg
)

Answer (score 0):

The two paths that you are morphing between have to have the same number and type of path **commands**.  Path commands are the single letters that appear in your path definition `d=""`.  You can read more about them in [the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

In your first SVG (arr.svg) there are X commands:

```
arr.svg           add.svg
--------------    --------------
M12.222,13.293    M29.000,22.000
L7.000,13.000     L22.000,22.000
L17.172,23.899    L22.000,29.000
L17.172,23.899    L18.000,33.000
L20.000,26.728    L18.000,22.000
L20.000,26.728    L7.000,22.000
L20.000,26.728    L10.000,18.000
L22.828,23.899    L18.000,18.000
L22.828,23.899    L18.000,10.000
L33.000,13.000    L22.000,7.000
L27.778,13.293    L22.000,18.000
L20.000,21.071    L32.000,18.000
L14.343,15.414    L29.000,22.000
                  Z
```

Your two SVGs almost match.  If you add a 'Z' to the first one, you should be able to animate them.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 121.5 60.834">
  
  <path d="">
    <animate attributeName="d" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
      values="M12.222,13.293 L7.000,13.000 L17.172,23.899 L17.172,23.899 L20.000,26.728 L20.000,26.728 L20.000,26.728 L22.828,23.899 L22.828,23.899 L33.000,13.000 L27.778,13.293 L20.000,21.071 L14.343,15.414 Z;
              M29.000,22.000 L22.000,22.000 L22.000,29.000 L18.000,33.000 L18.000,22.000 L7.000,22.000 L10.000,18.000 L18.000,18.000 L18.000,10.000 L22.000,7.000 L22.000,18.000 L32.000,18.000 L29.000,22.000 Z;
              M12.222,13.293 L7.000,13.000 L17.172,23.899 L17.172,23.899 L20.000,26.728 L20.000,26.728 L20.000,26.728 L22.828,23.899 L22.828,23.899 L33.000,13.000 L27.778,13.293 L20.000,21.071 L14.343,15.414 Z"/>
  </path>
  
</svg>
```